# External fingerprint device integration for android and flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, fingerprint

I'm working on an app that uses an external fingerprint device to capture fingerprints.
Morpho MSO 1300 E3 is the external fingerprint device.
This app is not being developed for India. As a result, the RD service does not work for me.

So, basically, I need to link that device to my Android and Flutter mobile application. So, after successfully connecting, I need to capture the fingerprint and extract the picture template's information.

Please assist.

I've been looking for SDK and sample code to connect that device and obtain information in image template, but I've had no luck.